# Counting with recursive functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a RECURSIVE function that takes a ternary letter tree and counts the number of uppercase letters in the tree.  I know this is a simple task to many experienced programmers, but I cannot figure out what to do.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def count_upper(tlt, ):
"""returns the number of uppercase letters in a ternary letter tree

tlt -> number"""
   if i.isupper():
       return count_upper(tlt, )
   else:
       return 0
```

Help if you can...

Comment: How did you create `tlt`?

Comment: something like ('a'('B','c')) @BillLynch

Comment: Please include some code showing how you create `tlt`.

Comment: the ternary letter tree (tlt) will be inputted by the user... I just used an example @BillLynch

Comment: What is the variable `i`?

Comment: maybe it's not needed? this was a really rough sketch of a code @nullstellensatz

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the TLT has nodes of type `Node` each of which is an object that has the properties `left`, `mid` and `right`, where each of these properties could be none (indicating no child). These members are of also of type `Node`. In addition, each `Node` has a member called `value` that is of type `str`. With this assumption, this function should do what you want.

```
def count_upper(node):
    children = [node.left, node.mid, node.right]
    child_count = 0
    for child in children:
        if child is not None:
            child_count += count_upper(child)
    return child_count + 1 if node.value.isupper() else child_count
```

To count the number of uppercase letters in a tree, invoke the function as thus: `count_upper(root)`

Comment: This IS recursive. :) Or did you mean iterative?

Comment: youre right.  I'm not allowed to use a for loop... ill see if i can work around that

Comment: The alternative to using a `for` loop for the children is to invoke the function on each of them individually. Repeating lines of code that can be replaced by a loop is poor programming. What exactly do you mean by not being allowed to use a `for` loop?

Comment: A more elegant way of writing the last line would be `return child_count + int(node.value.isupper())` and the for loop can be re-written as `child_count = sum(count_upper(child) for child in children if child is not None)` and then you don't need the `child_count = 0` line. But, good answer, I upvoted you :)